# Bootstrap btn-group inside form-group and border-radius

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, label

I try to remove border-radius of first child label with no success.
For example, I tried with no success:

```
.btn-group .label:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
}
```

The labels are inside btn-group which are inside form-group:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/row7L6kh/

[image]

How to remove first label border-radius top left and bottom left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `.label` to `.btn`. Because the CSS class you are changing for `btn-group` is `.btn`.

```
.btn span.glyphicon {               
    opacity: 0;             
}
.btn.active span.glyphicon {                
    opacity: 1;             
}

.btn-group .btn:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius:0;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/row7L6kh/1/)